# Eclipse Program Does Not Run Even With no Syntax Errors

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

So i need to create a program for the user to input match scores and exit by inputting "exit" when prompted. However this code does not run even though there is no errors

```
package Main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] names = new String[10];


        int index = 0;
        while (index<10) {

            index++;
            System.out.print("Home team name: ");
            names[index] = keyboard.nextLine();


            System.out.print("Away team name: ");
            names[index] = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter home score: ");
            names[index] = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter away score: ");
            names[index] = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("If you would liketo quit type exit: ");
            if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(keyboard.nextLine()));

            keyboard.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have very little knowledge of java and coding at this point, only very basic commands so i have no clue what is wrong.

Comment: `while (index<10);` --> infinite loop here. Check your syntax. Also once you've fixed, you'll run into an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but a simple google search will sort you out there. Then you'll run into an `IllegalStateException`. You can google that again, or just check the `Scanner` API better.

Comment: @Mena `while (index<10);` is perfectly valid syntax :-)

Comment: @GyroGearless not for what OP wants to do it isn't ;)

Comment: do you have the Console window open in Eclipse (Menu: Window > Show View > Console)?

Comment: I think you also have a problem here `if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(keyboard.nextLine()));` This way it will not run your `keyboard.close();` i guess.

Comment: okay it is the while loop that is the problem but is there any other way of using the loop differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some adjustments and your program can work.
I'm not considering if it's a good solution or not, but I think this is what you wanted to do. So now you can improve your solution, how you will exit the loop, how you want to use scanner and so on.

```
package Main;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] names = new String[10];

        int index = 0;
        while (index<10) {
            index++;
            System.out.print("Home team name: ");
            names[index] = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Away team name: ");
            names[index] = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter home score: ");
            names[index] = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter away score: ");
            names[index] = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("If you would like to quit type exit: ");
            if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(keyboard.nextLine())) {
                index = 10;
                keyboard.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this still doesnt run for me, its not liking the while loop altogether

Comment: Did you copy, compile and run exact this code? I don't know what you are trying to do, but it's working for sure. You can input the values in the console and see for yourself. Or maybe you have to give us more information about what you really need, because all hints in all answers are correct.

Comment: in the process of changning the code alogether to a do loop instead to get around this, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you have a semicollon after `if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(keyboard.nextLine()))`, so the `keyboard.close()` is always ececuted.

remove the `;` in line with `if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(keyboard.nextLine()))`

but closing the input will not end the while loop. rather add a `break;` command to exit the loop and close the keyboard after the loop for all cases, not only the for 'exit'